# Dynamically resizing a container DIV based on the image inside of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using the Resizable function to manipulate some images, and I'm wondering if it's possible to have a container DIV (Specifically .CONTAINER below) surrounds the images to resize dynamically along with the image inside of it. See this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jdcutter/6y1x9dwp/2/) for an example of sorta what I'm going for.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="resizable" class="ui-state-active">
      <img src="http://41.media.tumblr.com/3e99c08237117645f55cd1c4bdbf3180/tumblr_mky50dQmXI1s56exfo1_500.png" alt="doge">
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container { width: auto; height: auto; }

.resizable { background-position: top left; width: 150px; height: 200px; }
    .resizable, .container { padding: 0.5em; }
        .resizable img {width:100%;}
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $( ".resizable" ).resizable({
      containment: ".container",
      aspectRatio: 150/200
    });
});
```

Originally, I thought that maybe placing the containers width/height to AUTO would take care of the issue, however, that just 100% the DIVs length.

Thoughts?

Comment: You can try to use resize event and change width and height based on resizable size. http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#event-resize

Comment: So why not just [set `aspectRatio` to `true`](https://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/kcod5rsa/) as noted in [the documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-aspectRatio)?

Comment: Can you please confirm if this serve your purpose?
https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/6y1x9dwp/5/

Comment: @user2181397 no, sorry I should have specified. The DIV I'm looking to adjust is the one with the class CONTAINER. I'll edit my post above to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make this changes and it will work. Setting container width and height to auto, and displaying inline-block in order to not take the full parent width.

CSS

```
.container { width: auto; height: auto; display: inline-block; }

.resizable { background-position: top left; width: 150px; height: 200px; }
    .resizable, .container { padding: 0.5em; }
        .resizable img {width:100%;}
```

Also you have to delete the containment line of your js.

JS

```
$(function() {
    $( ".resizable" ).resizable({
        aspectRatio: 150/200
    });
});
```

Comment: That does the trick, but let me expand on this based on an item you called out. 

The containment JS that you saw was part of a secondary part I was working on. With the changes you've highlighted above – note: I did not remove the containment JS in my code – the images are now able to break containment upon resizing due to a portion of them still resides inside the containment. Do you have a suggestion using your update above in holding them entirely in that containment?

Comment: @JDCutter with the containment defined seems that the resizable can't be enlarged. Probably you will have to find a workaround, maybe something like dynamically resize the container on mouse dragged while you have the resizing arrows pressed.